# How do I normalize plotly express's histogram as probability density for multiple groups?

Tags: python, plotly

Let's take this toy df as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [1, 12, 16, 4, 27, 38, 19], "group": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
```

Using this df, we can build a histogram in plotly express with data normalized as probability density as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.histogram(toy_df, x="value", histnorm='probability density')
```

This will give us the following graph:

[image]

Now, if we manually calculate the cumulative area of both rectangles it adds up to 1.

But if we introduce the *group* column as *color* it gets probability densities separately for both groups:

```
px.histogram(toy_df, x="value", color = "group", histnorm='probability density')
```

[image]

How could I make them add up to 1 as well?

I investigated [the documentation of px.histogram](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html), but haven't found any parameter that could help with that.

I would appreciate any suggestion how this might be obtained within plotly express (I am pretty sure matplotlib is more flexible in this case).

Comment: You need to add `barmode = overlay` to your call for `px.histogram`. It might look like three colors when you render it, but it's just that the opacity is reduced (it's still 2 groups).

Comment: Thanks @Kat, I have tried that, but it is not what I am after. What I am trying to achieve is probability density calculated in the same manner as if there was no coloring applied (so the sum of probability densities of all bars should be equal to 1), but with coloring applied.